# does solidity support signed integers in regards to input arguments

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

Does Solidity support signed integer and negative input arguments or would require comparisons with `0` be meaningless?

E.g

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) public returns (bool success) {
        require( _to != 0x0);
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= _amount && _amount >= 0);
        balances[msg.sender] = (balances[msg.sender]).sub(_amount);
        balances[_to] = (balances[_to]).add(_amount);
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _amount);
             return true;
         }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Solidity supports signed integers, e.g. `int256`. Here's some code you can try in Remix to prove to yourself that it works as expected:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract Test {
    function isNegative(int256 x) public pure returns (bool) {
        return x < 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: in regards to the respected transfer & transferFrom functions, would it make sense to check for amount >= 0? I've always read that it would be meaningless

Comment: It depends whether they accept signed or unsigned integers. The ERC20 token standard dictates that they use unsigned integers (`uint256`), so checking for a negative number would make no sense.

Comment: So the erc20 token standard does actually not support signed ints however the EVM does. Is this how It should be understood? Allowing signed integers would therefore mean a token would not be erc20 compliant

Comment: I'd say Solidity, not the EVM, but otherwise yes. (I believe that at the EVM level, there's no differentiation between signed and unsigned integers.)

Comment: Can I ask why you would say solidity? I've seen multiple occasions of int implementations but I've also read quiet a few places that solidity does not support int atm.

Comment: As I said, I don't think that EVM knows anything about signed or unsigned integers. That interpretation is layered on top by the compiler. In most cases, that's Solidity.

Comment: Documentation for Solidity's types is here, in case there's still any doubt as to whether signed integers are supported: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#integers.

Comment: would I be able to underflow if I remove the check? thanks for helping out Marx you're really appreciated. Every time :)

Comment: Underflow what if you removed what check? I'm a little lost. I haven't seen any actual code except what I put in my answer (which does no arithmetic and thus can't overflow or underflow).

Comment: edited post and added an example :)

Comment: The `amount >= 0` check there is indeed meaningless. It can never be false, because `amount` is of type `uint256`.

Comment: Smarx would you be able to write an article on your website https://programtheblockchain.com about how wallets work? how to create your own wallet programingwise and not through MEW. So many people are looking into creating their own wallets these days and there is a lot of stuff to cover underneath such as ECDSA etc.